# Rails dynamic error pages and Devise: RuntimeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, runtime-error, ruby-on-rails-5, custom-error-pages

I read and tried to apply what Matt Brictson says in [his awesome article](https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages) about dynamic error pages on Rails.
I use Devise to authenticate users so I have to put authenticate_user to the `errors_controller.rb`

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:not_found, :internal_server_error]
```

But this fails giving me a RuntimeError in Errors#not_found when I try to call the `/404` page:

`can't add a new key into hash during Iteration`

[image]

**EDIT**: I post the `application.rb` code too:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

I18n.available_locales = [:en, :de]

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)


module SoundnotationBackend
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified 
here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
      config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 
'**', '*.{rb,yml}')]

    config.exceptions_app = self.routes

    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
    config.after_initialize do
      ::Git_branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT 2**: added (hopefully exhaustive) stack trace logged by Rails in development.log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (can't add a new key into hash during iteration):
     6:     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     7:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
     9:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    10:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'soundnotation8.ico' %>
    11:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    12:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__320037179907821997_69815613536340'
app/controllers/errors_controller.rb:4:in `not_found'
  Rendering /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (8.5ms)
  Rendering /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendering /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (71.6ms)
```

Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: There is no need to adding the authentication_user on errors page.

Comment: Ok but what if I'm not logged in? Will the pages be shown? If I remove that line and call the `/404` page, it redirects me to the sign_in page. But is that also the behavior when one raises an error?

Comment: This might be a bug in a third-party gem. Can you try the troubleshooting technique suggested at the bottom of this thread? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24627#issuecomment-217475139

Comment: Sorry @MattBrictson :) but we worked around in the end using [exception_handler](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler). Anyway, thanks for your article!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry [@Matt Brictson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4625365/matt-brictson) :) but we worked around in the end using [exception_handler](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler)